# How to determine whether all elements in a Collection have the same value with Stream IPA

Tags: java, list, boolean, java-stream, predicate

I am trying to search a *collection* and return `true` or `false` based on if every item in the *collection* has a matching `boolean` property.

I made a simple example where the 'falseList' returns `false`.

So my question, is there a stream call to cleanly check for matching `boolean` values in a collection, such that the 'falseList' will result in a `true` since all properties match?

I'm aware that I can get the first item in the collection and then compare all values to the first item with `allMatch()` in `2` lines, however I am looking for a one liner out of curiosity.

```
class BooleanClass {
    boolean val;

    public BooleanClass(boolean val) {
        this.val = val; 
    }

    public boolean getVal() {
        return this.val;
    }
}

public class AllMatch {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanClass a = new BooleanClass(true);
        BooleanClass b = new BooleanClass(true);
        BooleanClass c = new BooleanClass(true);

        ArrayList<BooleanClass> trueList = new ArrayList<BooleanClass>();
        trueList.add(a);
        trueList.add(b);
        trueList.add(c);

        System.out.println(trueList.stream().allMatch(l -> l.getVal())); // true

        BooleanClass d = new BooleanClass(false);
        BooleanClass e = new BooleanClass(false);
        BooleanClass f = new BooleanClass(false);

        ArrayList<BooleanClass> falseList = new ArrayList<BooleanClass>();
        falseList.add(d);
        falseList.add(e);
        falseList.add(f);

        System.out.println(falseList.stream().allMatch(l -> l.getVal())); // false
    }
}
```

*Current output*:

```
true
false
```

*Desired output*:

```
true
true
```

Comment: If you want to check if all elements have the same value for a certain property, then essentially you need to get the first element's value for said property and then compare the remaining elements' values for said property with the first one. This would probably be easier to implement with a separate method and a `for` loop, but I suppose you could also implement it via streams. You'll also need to decide what the result should be if the list is empty or has only a single element.

Comment: Maybe another option is to do something like `list.stream().map(Type::getProperty).distinct().count() == 1`. However, I believe you lose any short-circuiting behavior with that.

Comment: Isn’t `falseList.stream().allMatch(l -> l.getVal() == falseList.get(0).getVal()))` a one-liner? An alternative is `list.stream().map(BooleanClass::getVal).distinct().limit(2) == 1` but it builds a `Set` behind the scenes.

Comment: @Slaw you can short-circuit with `.distinct().limit(2).count() == 1` but still, taking the first element’s property and compare with this value is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return true or false based on if every item in the collection has a matching boolean property

So you need to check whether all elements in a *list* have the same value (either all `true` or all `false`). And you want to achieve that in a *single stream statement*.

You can do it with `anyMatch()`. The upper hand of checking with this operation over `allMatch()` is that `anyMatch()` is a ***short-circuit*** operation. I.e. when it encounters the element that doesn't match the given *predicate*, it terminates the execution of the stream pipe-line and return the result.

That how it might look like:

```
public static boolean isNonUniform(Collection<Boolean> list) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(el -> el.getVal() != falseList.get(0).getVal());
}
```

Method `isNonUniform()` as its name suggests and how you can see from the *predicate* passed into `anyMatch()`, checks whether the given collection contains at least one element that is different from the others.

*Note*, that accessing the first element of the list is *safe* because if the list is empty, the *predicate* will not be evaluated.

Also note that `anyMatch()` will return `false` when there are no elements in the stream. I.e. an empty list is considered to be uniform (*not nonUniform*). In case if you want to obtain `true` when the list is empty, then append this condition in front of the stream: `falseList.isEmpty() ||`. Technically, it still will be a one-liner.

So in order to determine if the list is uniform, it should be used this way:

```
System.out.println(!isNonUniform(falseList));
```

*Side-note*: I personally think that having `not` or `non` in the method name (*which is not perfect*) from the clean-coding perspective is smaller evil, then placing logical not `!` in front of the stream, which makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your question mentions `allMatch`, however, you are using `anyMatch` in your code. Either way, for something to evaluate to `true`, the lambda should evaluate to `true`. In your case, the first expression `l -> l.getVal()` always evaluates to `true`. For second expression `l -> l.getVal()` always evaluates to `false`, hence the effective result will be `false`. To make it `true`, you have to change the lambda to `l -> l.getVal() == false`. Not sure if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: good catch, let me edit to anyMatch my bad.
i am looking to achieve a boolean that tells me if all the properties match. ie if all are true then true or if all are false then true

Comment: There is no built-in method to do that.  You will have to check those possibilities separately.

Comment: Instead of using `allMatch` or `anyMatch`, you can add all elements to a `Set`. If the size of the collection is `1`, then you have unique set of elements. Again, it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Rather than `l -> l.getVal() == false` prefer `l -> ! l.getVal()` (exclamation mark means *not*).

Comment: @devang Approach of utilizing a `Set` is simple and clear, but will require to process all elements in the source list. Conversely, with streams, in order to produce the result the source data could be processed only partially ([with anyMatch()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888532/17949945) or by using a combination `distinct().limit().count()==1` as Holger suggested).